# How could I get the bluetooth UUIDs of my own android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, sdp

I currently can `fetchUuidsWithSdp` of a **remote** device. *(`getUuids` doesn't work, not sure why)*

But how could I get the UUIDs of my own android device?

It is **supposed** that when I successfully execute `accept()` upon a **server socket** the registered UUIDs **must** include the UUID I established upon the creation of the server socket with this command `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord`

I discovered this is **not** always the case! I would like to test it..

Comment: Did you get your answer , i am also looking to find the UUID of my own device.

Answer (score 1):

Hey a Little Late but the best method I found is to do something like this. I isn't neccesary the best idea for production code but for testing it's not bad.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
Method getUUIDsMethod = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null);
ParcelUuid[] dUUIDs = (ParcelUuid[]) getUUIDsMethod.invoke(mBluetoothAdapter, null);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();
//or
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(tManager.getDeviceId().getBytes("utf8"))
```

Comment: the question is related to bluetooth, not telephony :)